# My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop

Tags: 20.04, performance

My screen gets frozen when I'm doing multiple tasks. No keyboard key works and I have to do a manual shutdown of the laptop when this happens. So far it's been four times in three days.

Also if I play a song on Spotify it works as a loop between 2s in a song.

I am a new user of Ubuntu. My system has 8GB ram and a swap partition of 16GB I used.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What GPU is inside ?

Answer (score 3):

Your 16GB swap partition is large enough that it rules out insufficient swap space as a possible cause of freezing and audio looping.

Your computer's glitchy performance is characteristic of video RAM artifacts. If the RAM in your graphics processor is failing, sometimes just a small fraction of the RAM goes bad while the rest of the RAM continues to work properly. This results in the part of the operating system or program that was being stored in that RAM malfunctioning. Sometimes as a result of this the screen also freezes or a section of audio plays repeatedly in a loop. Rebooting the computer also clears whatever was stored in the RAM, and the laptop's performance goes back to normal.

If the situation becomes intolerable you may have to disable the [discrete graphics](https://superuser.com/a/1107633/) on your computer and use only the integrated graphics.

Comment: Thanks for your information