# Sound problem with dual boot Asus vivobook pro 14x

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, amd-ryzen

I have some problems with my new Asus laptop , AMD 5600H + rtx 3050

After installing window, I installed pop OS with Nvidia driver ( dual boot ), everything seem to be fine, but after switching from popos to window, there are some problem with sound so I tried to reinstall driver, It seems to be fine but after reset sound problem appear again. If after trying to remove the pop os partition, the sound problem disappears!!!

I tried to replace Pop OS with Ubuntu but nothing changed.

Is this problem related to the boot partition ?

Comment: I believe Pop OS is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu. See the answer [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19447/can-we-warn-new-users-that-questions-about-kali-linux-pop-os-and-so-on-are-off). You might try [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). btw, run `apt search nvidia-settings`. That should help. DL & configure, and you should be ok.

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu also so I believe this is err related to ubuntu problem

Comment: Pop OS is off-topic as it's not Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)  but your question is *unclear*.  We don't know what on-topic release/ISO you are talking about, nor what you actually did to try and *fix* your issue; you mainly documented off-topic stuff beforehand (*maybe useful as background, but again without actual specifics*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364590/my-screen-freezes-when-im-multitasking-and-videos-loop)

Answer (score -1):

I too have the same issue with my Vivobook pro, I got a temporary solution to fix this issue.

```
sudo #!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Run this script then use the power button to shutdown your system(The normal power Off/restart/ with sudo privilege also didn't fix). I don't know how but this fixed my system. This will solve the issue until you boot to windows again, then you have to redo the process. I don't know if there is any other methods available to fix this issue permanently, but this is the only method that worked for me after trying multiple methods.

Comment: It is a bad idea to power off a running system you are asking for system corruption.

Comment: Yes, But it didn't fix until I do so.