# Crashing whole screen in my ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I am new to ubuntu . It's really cool to use but I'm having problem when watching utube
or sometimes stopped  when started browser.Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS & it is suitable for my laptop's spec.Please,anyone can help me?I'm really being worry to watch utube for now...

Comment: Please [Edit] (click the link)  your question and show use how much RAM and swap you have. Use the terminal command `free` to see this information

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: It 's chrome.But it is also being on firefox.I am having problem is just while watching video contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364590/my-screen-freezes-when-im-multitasking-and-videos-loop)