# Youtube videos freezes regularly

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, firefox, youtube

I'm on Kubuntu 22.10 running an NVIDIA GPU with a proprietary driver version 525.78.01 (same problem occured on 525.60.11 too). Starting from approximately a week ago I experience videos in YouTube played in Firefox freezing: the actual video is still playing, the progress slider advances and the audio is played back, just the picture is frozen at an older time step. This happening when I move the slider manually to different times within the video. This also affects to a lesser extent in Facebook videos. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364590/my-screen-freezes-when-im-multitasking-and-videos-loop)