# Ubuntu 22.04 display freezes randomly, but ONLY for local display

Tags: 22.04, mouse, freeze

Randomly my whole ubuntu 22.04 system will randomly freeze. I cannot move the mouse. Any audio I have will continue to play, and if I am on a screenshare with someone, it appears to anyone watching my screen that nothing is frozen. My mouses still moves and everything. Anyone have an idea of what might be going on? I am on a Dell XPS 13 plus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My screen freezes when I'm multitasking and videos loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364590/my-screen-freezes-when-im-multitasking-and-videos-loop)